# Extracted files from zip using JSZip return plain text files

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jszip

I have this code in my vue app to read zip files

```
    handleFiles(e) {
      let file = e.dataTransfer.files[0];
      JSZip.loadAsync(file).then( (zip) => {
        Object.keys(zip.files).forEach( (filename) => {
          this.filesList.push(filename);
          zip.file(filename).async('blob').then( (blob) => {
            this.files.push({name: filename, data: blob});
          });  
        });
      });
    }
```

I'm trying to download the files that are inside a zip when the user click on it. I'm using JSZip. I'm able to read the content of the zip but the problems starts when I try to download the files. They are saved as plain text, this because I've noticed that the files blob will not include the files type. I'm using vue inside a chrome extension and I'm passing this configuration to the download API

```
downloadFile(i) {
        let downloadURL = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[i].data);
        browser.downloads.download({
          saveAs: false,
          filename: this.files[i].name,
          url: downloadURL
        }).then( (downloadId) => {
          URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadURL);
          console.log(downloadId)
        });
}
```

How I can fix this?

Comment: You say the files are saved as plain text, but do they contain any (binary) data as well?

Comment: I mean that the save dialog will prompt to save the files as text and will not apply the file extension that is in the file name. The zipped files can be all different, they can be images, text files or pdf or any file the user choiche to zip. This means that if the user will zip an svg image, when the archive is opened and the user want to extract back the svg image, he expect o get an svg file not a plain thext file.

Comment: Yes it's clear to me that it should work like that. Why I asked is if the blob that is provided is somehow empty the browser might offer it as plain/text. If the blob is not empty it and there is no mime information to help it it will probably say its an `application/octet-stream` (i presume)

Comment: blob are not empty but the mime type is non provided by jszip. I'm thinking to replace the download api of crome with file saver library that will hold the save also without mime type